# Detect changes in subsequent rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table in which there are 2 columns, one is the timestamp and the other is a value field. The value field can change over time. The entries in the table are entered at every minute.

```
    TimeStamp  Value    
    1          0
    2          0
    3          0  
    4          0
    5          2
    6          6
    7          6
    8          7
```

I want to detect the rows where the value changes. I need and SQL that will return the result set  as

```
    5             2
    6             6
    8             7
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by finding the previous value.  Here is a method using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.timestamp, t.value
from (select t.*,
             (select top 1 t2.value
              from table t2
              where t2.timestamp < t.timestamp
              order by t2.timestamp desc
             ) as prevvalue
      from table t
     ) t
where prevvalue is null or prevvalue <> value;
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012, you can do this more easily using `lag()`:

```
select t.timestamp, t.value
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (order by timestamp desc) as prevvalue
      from table t
     ) t
where prevvalue is null or prevvalue <> value;
```

Comment: Can it be done using cursors ? Since the data in the database will be ordered by the timestamp can we not use cursors to compare two rows ?

Comment: You *can*.  In general, you want to avoid cursors, if you can use a single query for the same purpose (for performance and maintenance reasons).